# What's wrong with my cross compiling makefile?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, cross-compiling, mingw32

I have spent several days now trying to cross compile a c program on my windows machine. the code runs fine on my linux machine but I had too many errors trying to cross compile it on that machine. Now I'm using Cygwin and Mingw32.

```
    CC = x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
    CFLAGS = -Wall -O2 -lmingw32 -lGL -lGLU -lm -lSDL_image -lfftw3 -lftdi1 
    -mwindows `sdl-config --cflags --libs`

    OBJECTS = main.o fft.o draw.o table.o serial.o

    main : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o main

    %.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

    clean:
    @echo Cleaning up...
    rm -fr *.o main
    @echo Done.
```

This is what my makefile looks like after editing it to what I thought was needed to cross compile it. But I get many undefined reference errors. I realize this question is very similar to a few others I've looked over on SO, but I cannot seem to find my mistake.

```
 $ make
 x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wall -O2 -lmingw32 -lGL -lGLU -lm -lSDL_image - 
 lfftw3 -lftdi1 -mwindows `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -c main.c
 x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wall -O2 -lmingw32 -lGL -lGLU -lm -lSDL_image - 
 lfftw3 -lftdi1 -mwindows `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -c fft.c
 x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wall -O2 -lmingw32 -lGL -lGLU -lm -lSDL_image - 
 lfftw3 -lftdi1 -mwindows `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -c draw.c
 x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wall -O2 -lmingw32 -lGL -lGLU -lm -lSDL_image - 
 lfftw3 -lftdi1 -mwindows `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -c table.c
 x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wall -O2 -lmingw32 -lGL -lGLU -lm -lSDL_image - 
 lfftw3 - 
 lftdi1 -mwindows `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -c serial.c
 x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wall -O2 -lmingw32 -lGL -lGLU -lm -lSDL_image - 
 lfftw3 - 
 lftdi1 -mwindows `sdl-config --cflags --libs` main.o fft.o draw.o table.o 
 serial.o -o main
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): In function `main':
/usr/src/debug/mingw64-x86_64-runtime-5.0.3-1/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain'
fft.o:fft.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `fftw_malloc'
fft.o:fft.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `fftw_malloc'
fft.o:fft.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `fftw_malloc'
fft.o:fft.c:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d'
fft.o:fft.c:(.text+0x73d): undefined reference to `fftw_execute'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `__imp_glShadeModel'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `__imp_glClearColor'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `gluOrtho2D'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `__imp_glDisable'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `__imp_glEnable'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `__imp_glViewport'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to `__imp_glMatrixMode'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x97): undefined reference to `__imp_glLoadIdentity'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `gluOrtho2D'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0xeb): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0xf4): undefined reference to `SDL_GetVideoInfo'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x11c): undefined reference to `SDL_GL_SetAttribute'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x13a): undefined reference to `SDL_SetVideoMode'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x171): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x1a1): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x1d1): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x244): undefined reference to `__imp_glBegin'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x24b): undefined reference to `__imp_glColor3ub'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x252): undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex2f'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x29f): undefined reference to `__imp_glEnd'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x415): undefined reference to `__imp_glBegin'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x42c): undefined reference to `__imp_glColor3ub'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x447): undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex2f'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x4ef): undefined reference to `__imp_glEnd'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x55b): undefined reference to `__imp_glColor3ub'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x574): undefined reference to `__imp_glBegin'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x580): undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex2f'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x5e4): undefined reference to `__imp_glEnd'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x602): undefined reference to `__imp_glColor3ub'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x638): undefined reference to `__imp_glBegin'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x648): undefined reference to `__imp_glColor3ub'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x664): undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex2f'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x6b8): undefined reference to `__imp_glEnd'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x6e8): undefined reference to `__imp_glBegin'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x6fb): undefined reference to `__imp_glColor3ub'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x717): undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex2f'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x76b): undefined reference to `__imp_glEnd'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x7b5): undefined reference to `__imp_glBegin'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x80d): undefined reference to `__imp_glColor3ub'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x814): undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex2f'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x935): undefined reference to `__imp_glEnd'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0xa00): undefined reference to `__imp_glBegin'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0xa07): undefined reference to `__imp_glColor3ub'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0xa0e): undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex2f'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0xb0b): undefined reference to `__imp_glEnd'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0xc09): undefined reference to `__imp_glBegin'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0xc10): undefined reference to `__imp_glColor3ub'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0xc19): undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex2f'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0xc20): undefined reference to `__imp_glEnd'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0xea7): undefined reference to `__imp_glClear'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0xeb2): undefined reference to `__imp_glMatrixMode'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0xeb8): undefined reference to `__imp_glLoadIdentity'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0xec7): undefined reference to `__imp_glTranslatef'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0xf48): undefined reference to `__imp_glBegin'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0xf72): undefined reference to `__imp_glColor3ub'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0xf8f): undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex2f'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0xfba): undefined reference to `__imp_glEnd'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x1089): undefined reference to `SDL_GL_SwapBuffers'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x10c3): undefined reference to `__imp_glColor3ub'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x10d8): undefined reference to `SDL_GetKeyState'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x133d): undefined reference to `SDL_WM_ToggleFullScreen'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x1364): undefined reference to `SDL_PollEvent'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x1385): undefined reference to `SDL_PollEvent'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x13ab): undefined reference to `SDL_SetVideoMode'
draw.o:draw.c:(.text+0x13e1): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
serial.o:serial.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `ftdi_init'
serial.o:serial.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `ftdi_set_interface'
serial.o:serial.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `ftdi_usb_open'
serial.o:serial.c:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `ftdi_set_baudrate'
serial.o:serial.c:(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `ftdi_get_error_string'
serial.o:serial.c:(.text+0xc7): undefined reference to `ftdi_get_error_string'
serial.o:serial.c:(.text+0x139): undefined reference to `ftdi_write_data'
serial.o:serial.c:(.text+0x233): undefined reference to `ftdi_write_data'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:6: main] Error 1
```

Comment: I seem to remember that the `-lwhatever` options must be after the object files, due to the way the linker works in Windows. It is usually better to separate `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` for the compiler and linker options.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I moved things around so `-lfiles` are after objects, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you post the full linker command that is actually running?

Comment: Are you referring to what the output I see in terminal is when I type make?

Comment: Well, yes, the most interesting line is that call to `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` with `-o main` and all the other stuff.

Comment: But you still have the `-l*` before the object files!

Comment: Ah, I copied the code from BEFORE I changed that, haha. ok what about now?

Comment: I guessed so much... could you post that command line AFTER the change? And also could you check any error messages are different with that change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you link to a SO in Linux , for example with `-lGL`, you are linking the shared object directly `libGL.so`.

But in Windows, when you link a DLL you are actually linking a static library `libGL.a` (`libGL.lib` in native Windows) that contains one thunk per imported function.

And as it happens, linker rules are different between shared and static libraries. Static libraries are linked using the order in the linker command line.

**TL;DR;** You have to put the `-l*` at the end of the linker command. Also, it is a good practice to separate `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`:

```
CC = x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -O2 `sdl-config --cflags`
LDFLAGS = -lmingw32 -lGL -lGLU -lm -lSDL_image -lfftw3 -lftdi1 -mwindows `sdl-config --libs`

OBJECTS = main.o fft.o draw.o table.o serial.o

main : $(OBJECTS)
$(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)

%.o : %.c
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

About the `WinMain` reference, that is because you wrote `-mwindows`: that is to build a Windows application, that is one that starts with `WinMain()` instead of `main()`. If you want to stick to your `main()` you can use `-mconsole` instead.

Comment: Ah ok, I see the difference there. Layout looks more organized too.
I tried changing -mwindows to -mconsole and no change to error

Comment: Still no advance on the `WinMain` reference. I've tried adding `#include <windows.h>` into my main.c file that I read somewhere. also, my main.c does have a line that says `int main` so could that be causing some problem? do I need to do something to cygwin to make it look for something else?

Comment: Ahh! You are using SDL so you have that infamous `SDL_main` issue. You can try linking with `SDL_main.a` OR adding `#undef main` just before your `main` function.

Comment: hey! `#ifdef main
# undef main
#endif /* main */` worked!

Comment: Now I have my .exe! but when I try to run it, I get several missing .dll errors including cygftdi-1.2.dll cygGLU-1.dll cygfftw3-3.dll cygGL-1.dll

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Cygwin internals, just with MinGW... But do you have those DLLs in the PATH? Also I have heard that you can have problems if you mix MinGW and Cygwin improperly...

Comment: I find them in my ..\cygwin\lib directory but they all have `.dll.a` can I copy these to another location so the .exe can find them?

Comment: I don't think so, you need the real DLL. I think Cygwin comes with a package manager, so that is where to begin. Then you have to add the directory to the PATH or copy the DLLs to the same directory where the EXE is.

Comment: Ok, I did use the package manager to add fftw3, ftdi1, GLU, and GL, so now I just need to figure out how to add them to the PATH. Is that something I need to go back and add to the makefile?

Comment: No, the PATH is an environment variable, nothing to do with the Makefile.

Comment: Ok now I found all the .dll files without the .a in my cygwin/bin folder

Answer (score 0):

I switched the objects and cflags at the top, but forgotten to switch objects and cflags in

`main : $(OBJECTS)
$(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS) -o main`

Now I only get a undefined reference to WinMain

```
$ make
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wall -O2 -lmingw32 -lm -lGL -lGLU -lSDL_image - 
lfftw3 -lftdi1 -mwindows `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -c main.c
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wall -O2 -lmingw32 -lm -lGL -lGLU -lSDL_image - 
lfftw3 -lftdi1 -mwindows `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -c fft.c
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wall -O2 -lmingw32 -lm -lGL -lGLU -lSDL_image - 
lfftw3 -lftdi1 -mwindows `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -c draw.c
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wall -O2 -lmingw32 -lm -lGL -lGLU -lSDL_image - 
lfftw3 -lftdi1 -mwindows `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -c table.c
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wall -O2 -lmingw32 -lm -lGL -lGLU -lSDL_image - 
lfftw3 -lftdi1 -mwindows `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -c serial.c
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc main.o fft.o draw.o table.o serial.o -Wall -O2 - 
lmingw32 -lm -lGL -lGLU -lSDL_image -lfftw3 -lftdi1 -mwindows `sdl-config -- 
cflags --libs` -o main
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys- 
root/mingw/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): In function 
`main':
/usr/src/debug/mingw64-x86_64-runtime-5.0.3-1/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined 
reference to `WinMain'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:6: main] Error 1
```